# deactivate browser notifications in chrome driver for selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a simple user login, which shows a notification (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) or an alert (if notifications were disabled), if the login fails.

Furthermore I want to test this login with selenium in NodeJS, but without the notifications (only alerts). So I tried to deactivate the notification feature in chrome using the chrome experimental options. Nevertheless it does show the notification. Perhaps this feature isn't supported atm.

I've tried the following in NodeJS:

```
var options = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", "2");
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(options.toCapabilities()).build();
```

The following code works in Java.

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to set the userPreferences.

```
var options = new chrome.Options();
options.setUserPreferences({'profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications': 2});
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(options.toCapabilities()).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code Works.
This is only for Chrome

```
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
opt.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
opt.AddArguments("--disable-popup-blocking"); 
driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\ChromeDriverPath", opt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this issue from many clients especially when the user is using WebdriverIO nodeJS bindings.The below code snippets for JS and Java work to enable the location settings:

For JS:

```
var options = new chrome.Options();
    options.setUserPreferences({'profile': {'managed_default_content_settings': {'geolocation': 1}}});
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').withCapabilities(options.toCapabilities()).build();
```

For Java:

```
// Declare variables
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 Map<String, Object> profile = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 Map<String, Object> contentSettings = new HashMap<String, Object>();
// Specify the ChromeOption we need to set
 contentSettings.put(“geolocation”, 1);
 profile.put(“managed_default_content_settings”, contentSettings);
 prefs.put(“profile”, profile);
 options.setExperimentalOption(“prefs”, prefs);
// Declare the capability for ChromeOptions
 caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `toCapabilities` method now. Just pass the options

```
const options = new chrome.Options();
options.setUserPreferences({'profile': {'managed_default_content_settings': {'geolocation': 2 }}});
this.driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').withCapabilities(options).build();
```